# Exception handling approch to multiple method form , running in a single thread

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm writing a form oriented application, that have many cotrols and actions. 
typically, each control is associated with an action (a function) that involves other objects of the application, that are generally should be initialized at point of call.

however, some scnarios may lead to a state where one or more of those objects are `null` , an thus using them results an exception.

the problem is, that it fills like theres a better way of handling this issue , other that wrapping each method of the form with a `try/catch` block.

Comment: Hard to characterize such a mishap as anything but a bug.  You can use the `Lazy<>` class to make it easier to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to catch exceptions at their heighest level where the provided information of type and origin is the most gerneralized or unspecific. You have to catch exceptions where they occur and especially react as specific as possible. This means: Try to filter each possible exception seperately.

But before (raw) exception handling comes into focus (e.g. nullArgumentException or InvalidIndexExcetion) its better to prevent them by checking possible issues inside your code or/ and write unit tests to find more of those possible problems. When using an object which state is unknown check for null. If the type is unknown check the type before using it. Check if an index is in bounds before using it... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all of your unhandled exceptions using [Application.ThreadException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Um well yes, but then what do you do with them?

Comment: Whatever you want :) I log them. You can "mute" them or anything else

Comment: Just had this awful feeling someone would use your answer to swallow the lot and continue on it's soon to be less than merry way...

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a bit messy. 
You can trap all the exceptions by adding and eventhandler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` in your `program.cs` file. That will save you having to wrap try catch round everything. 
However that's not the real solution. You should only handle exceptions when you can do so successfully and you should do as local to the problem as you can get.

E.g. if you had a UI that let you create a message in one action
and then a button that emailed it in another.

The email button should check to see if there's a message or should only be enabled if a message has been created.
You should not use try catch for it's existence, that should be for say can't find a mail server, something exceptional you can't deal with in code.

So while you could put a top level exception handler in and respond with say "Sorry I can;t do that", it's not going to make your code better if it happens a lot, it should be you see, an exception...